# How to create an anchorPoint to fill the whole iOS screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to design a Swift game but I noticed that I am unable to have the ball in the game go into the top left corner of the screen. I set my anchor point below.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {    
    anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
}
```

I noticed that if I change the anchor point's y-coordinate to 0, I am only able to access the right half of the screen and there's an invisible wall on the left half.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a bit confusing. is the Sprite called anchorPoint? If you can't get the position right, try setting the Sprite to the centre of the screen first, then change the x and y positions gradually so you can experiment with where the Sprite ends up on the screen. Set it to the center like this:

```
spriteName.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.5)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I fixed the problem, it was in another function I was using that created a new PhysicsBody.